# Caption an image, but not setting a fixed width on parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div, with an image.

I want the caption to sit under the image without expanding the width of the parent div. I do not want to set a fixed width on the parent div; I want it to expand to the size of the image, and this to be the width at which the text breaks for a new line.

```
<div>
     <img src=http://placehold.it/140x140>
     <span>this is a caption this is a caption this is a 
           caption this is a caption
     </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6eosgzr0/

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it in a table like so

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/multimedia/archive/00309/108787995_309592c.jpg" alt="cat" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste iure eum quidem dolore dignissimos neque molestias velit praesentium minima architecto voluptas suscipit excepturi tempore accusantium aperiam beatae culpa quaerat vero.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j58nns7k/

But that would be very unsemantic. I would recommend the new HTML5 elements figure and figcaptions:

```
<figure>
    <img src="path/to/image" alt="alt text" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and set a max-width to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style as below in the CSS.

```
div {
   margin: 50px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: table;
}
span {
   display: table-caption;
   caption-side: bottom;
}
```

Follow this link

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/g0r2kxpv/)